# Perform a click on a web app with selenium python (repost)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape or crawl this web app (https://www.ea.com/en-gb/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/) I not sure if its because its a web app or some anti scraper measures but nothing is happening when I attempt to click the login button.

the button is clicked but doesn't show anything.

Code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.ea.com/en-gb/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Login"]/div/div/button[1]').click()
```

Comment: With Chrome dev-tools open, can you see an outgoing HTTP request after the button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath needs to be updated. Note that the xpath I used is not the only way to di this `button[contains(text(), "Login")]` would also work in this scenario. And I would use `By`, `WebDriverWait`,  and `expected_conditions` instead of `driver.implicitly_wait(20)` see below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.ea.com/en-gb/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/")

click_this = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Login"]//*//button[contains(text(), "Login")]')))
click_this.click()
```

Comment: Faster would be `find_element_by_css_selector(".call-to-action").click()`. I note you say other methods. I just don't want to add more answers when yours is sufficient.